# Changing SSL Certificate and associated domain gives a 401 when it didn't before

Tags: spring, security, https, client, basic-authentication

I have an application with multiple services. One of them is the auth service that takes care of creating the jwt after checking that the client id (i.e. browser or app) is valid and provided username/password is also valid.

I have another service (gateway) that redirect to other services any requests from the users using the jwt token for authentication.

All this works and has been working for a few years. It is based on Spring Boot using Spring Security (starter v2.1.5). It is soon time to renew our certificate and at the same time move to our new domain. The new certificate has been applied to the Google Cloud Platform load balancer.

The call for health check using the Spring Actuator is responding with the proper "UP" (in json) response. When I try to make the call from same Postman request (with new domain name used) I get the following response with a 401 code:

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

I do have the proper clientid and password/secrete encoded using base64 (hey it worked before and nothing else was changed).

I tried to debug setting @EnableWebSecurity(debug = true), but it generates zero logs from the request.

If I switch back the certificate to old one (and old domain), it works again without any other changes. This has been driving me a bit on the crazy side to say the least. Any help, suggestion, ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: If it's domain did you examine if JWT token is only valid for old domain(e.g. issued by SSO on old hostname(new hostname) but is checked against auth app/SSO server  on the new hostname(old hostname)? If it's certificate then may be your clients do not know about/trust the new certificate of SSO server. I think tailing logs of the SSO server is the best approach here

Comment: Put the results below as an answer. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being an error on my part. When I added a A class resources during the copy paste of Load Balancer IP, I put the same IP for both of my services (i.e. one of the copy didn't stick). Ending up in calling security on the gateway service when asking for the auth token.

Thanks for the comment @Boris-Treukhov